# Шаблонизатор Twig (php)

Tags: шаблоны, twig, шаблонизаторы, php

Скажите пожалуйста, работаю с twig темплейтом.Передаю в качестве переменной строки таблицы в таком виде:

```
...........................
while ($rows=$db->fetchAssoc($monterData))
        {
        $content.="<tr><td>$rows[monter_name]</td><td></td></tr>";
        }                   
     ........................ 
      $template->display(array('datacontent'=>$content));?>
```

а в шаблоне просто таблица:

```
{% include 'header.html' %}
<div id="main" class="body">
         <table>

     {{datacontent}}

     </table>
</div>   
{% include 'footer.html'  %}
```

У меня строки не вставляеться,а выводить их отдельно
:

```
<div class="body" id="main">
  /tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;[НЕТ]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;[НЕТ]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;[НЕТ]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;[НЕТ]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;[НЕТ]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;[НЕТ]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;[НЕТ]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;[НЕТ]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;[НЕТ]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;[НЕТ]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;[НЕТ]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;[НЕТ]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;

     <table></table>
</div>
```

Почему так?

Comment: {{ datacontent | raw}} надо было,оказываеться.
вот ссылка:http://symf.ru/docs/html/book/templating.html#id14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте записать в шаблоне

```
{% autoescape false %}
{{datacontent}}
{% endautoescape %}
```

В более ранних версиях (судя по документации должно было работать:

```
{{ datacontent|safe }}
```

Но сейчас фильтр `safe` почему-то отсутствует в поставке twig

А вообще приведенный вами пример из разряда как не нужно делать. Правильнее все генерацию таблицы перенести в шаблон, а в twig передавать только данные

Comment: Ошибки очень много:....
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'The filter "safe" does not exist in "mainpage.php" at line 8' in /usr/local/www/pear/Twig/Node/Expression/Filter.php:29 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/www/pear/Twig/Compiler.php(81): Twig_Node_Expression_Filter->compile(Object(Twig_Compiler)) #1 /usr/local/www/pear/Twig/Node/Expression/Filter.php(41):

Comment: А какую версию twig вы используете, так как в [документации][1] совершенно четко написанно про использование `|safe`

  [1]: http://twig.kron0s.com/a/02-twig-for-template-designers

Comment: Twig-v1.4.0-25, да...там так написан. А не нужно ли включать cache?

Comment: Похоже что у них там ошибка, сейчас скачал последний дистрибутив - те-же проблемы, но можно решить по-другому:

    {% autoescape false %}
    {{datacontent}}
    {% endautoescape %}

Должно работать, а авторам Twig нужно писать bugreport, что в версии такой-то сломали `|safe`

Comment: Абсолютно верно.Работаеть.Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Ответ исправил, баг-репорт написал